# Term for if someone puts you in danger just to save you and collect a reward

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For instance, in my dream last night I noticed a wolf in my room creeping towards me, but then a big dog came in the room and scared the wolf away. The dog belonged to two brothers, who started asking me for a cash reward for sending their dog to save my life. However, I accused them of sending the wolf in there intentionally, just to collect a reward after saving me.

Is there a term for this?

Comment: related(?) to [Pyrrhic victory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory)

Comment: [**Munchausen Hero Homicide** is the male version of **Munchausen Mom Syndrome** where (mainly men) fabricate situations where they can be the hero!](http://www.healpastlives.com/pastlf/karmdict/kdherohm.htm) Also [**Hero Homicide:** Murders committed by a person looking for recognition without intent to kill. Often committed by heath care providers, these murders are the result of an unsuccessful **attempt to hurt somebody and later come to the rescue and save that person.**](http://criminalmindsworld.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/criminal-minds-glossary-of-terms-and.html)

Comment: Terrific answer. What the poster describes is very specifically Munchausen Hero Homicide. Well done!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why don't you post your answer as an answer?

Comment: A lot of Indian films have this plotline... The Hero himself either pays his cronies or hires a bunch of thugs to harass his love interest. When she hits panic mode, the Hero enters the scene and hurts all those who ragged his girl and then the frame cuts to a love song! :D

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Hm! That's crazy. I seem to recall a Flight of the Conchords episode where they attempted and failed such a scheme.

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like some sort of ***[protection racket](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/protection-racket)***

> a criminal activity in which money gangsters extort money from victims in exchange for freedom from molestation  - *ran a major protection racket involving 100 pubs and bars*

<sub>Collins Dictionary</sub>

A protection racket is itself a type of ***[extortion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/extortion)***

> the practice of obtaining something, especially money, through force or threats

<sub>OED</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If they were seeking to collect money from someone else - letting the wolf kill you and collecting money from life insurance or will - that's *fraud*